# How to combine static and dynamic views in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is a hard question to ask without some background on what I am trying to do.  I am working on an existing multitenant ASP.NET MVC 3 application (typical forms over data application) but now have to provide the ability for tenants to add custom fields to any page.  There is a fixed set of pages that all tenants have but they can add a field anywhere on one of those pages.  For example, on a User Profile page which has fields to enter your address a tenant might want to add a County field before the Country field.

The configuration of the custom fields for each tenant are stored in a database which includes information that describes what the field is (textbox, select, etc.) and where it should be rendered such as the route and the id of field it should be inserted before.

Since this is an existing application I have some limitations and wanted to keep all the existing .cshtml Views as the default/base that all tenants have.  To get the tenant specific fields added to a page I created a custom VirtualPathProvider that:

1. Load the standard View defined in the .cshtm file from the standard Views dir
2. Load the custom field definitions for the view from the database (specific to the tenant making the request)
3. For each custom field create Razor markup and insert that into the loaded view from step one
4. Return the combined view that now has both the base and tenant specific code

That design works fine for the first request for a view however, subsequent requests from any tenant just returns the first version.  I am pretty sure what is happening here is the ASP.NET runtime is compiling and caching the view so the next request for the view is just coming out of the cache.

So finally the question.  How can you override the compilation and caching so you can include something like the id of the tenant so each view is cached once per tenant?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that you can override the VirtualPathProviders's GetCacheKey method to implement your own key pattern.  In my case adding the tenant's key to the end of the cache key like this:

```
public override string GetCacheKey(string virtualPath)
{
    var tenantKey = getTenantKey();

    if (VirtualPathHelper.SupportsCustomFields(virtualPath))
    {
        return string.Join("_", virtualPath, tenantKey);
    }

    return base.GetCacheKey(virtualPath);
}
```

In the ASP.NET Temporary Internet files directory the file name for that view would be:
_views_home_index.cshtml_a7c1a66a-ebe4-4ca2-8dc4-7a22b460f368.compiled

Each tenant that requests a view will now get their own version.